# EF Core DbContext Where Async

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to execute a query that contains a WHERE as an Async function. Just like using the [`FirstAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.queryableextensions.firstasync?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) action, but there's no `WhereAsync` so I was wondering if there is some workaround.

I have an `ApplicationRepository` object that has an `GetEntitiesAsync` function and I tried this:

```cs
public async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> GetEntitiesAsync<TEntity>(Func<TEntity, bool> selector) where TEntity : class => 
            await _context.Set<TEntity>().Where(selector).AsQueryable().ToArrayAsync();
```

However, this line of code throws an exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The source IQueryable doesn't implement IAsyncEnumerable<OneStopApp.Models.CustomForm>. Only sources that implement IAsyncEnumerable can be used for Entity Framework asynchronous operations.
```

Comment: That `AsQueryable` doesn't seem necessary? Why have you included it?

Comment: I just figured it out, If you use an expression and pass it to the `Where` action it works. So the function should look like `GetEntitiesAsync<TEntity>(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> selector)`. My guess is that in the `DbContext` needs an `Expression` in order to translate it to a SQL query.

Comment: There is no `WhereAsync` because `Where` does not do I/O.  It only builds up the code that will eventually be translated to SQL.  Only the methods that materialize the query are async like `ToListAsync` or `CountAsync`.

Answer (score 7):

There is an `ToListAsync` method that can be called asynchronously to get the data.

```
var list = await db.Accounts.Where(x => true).ToListAsync();
```

Fetching the data takes the bulk of time, therefore async is not on the `Where` method, but it is on methods that get the data like `ToArrayAsync` or `FirstAsync`.

Answer (score 0):

The `Where` clause doesn't actually do anything, it's deferred execution. You can just use `FirstAsync`, `ToListAsync`, or `ToArrayAsync` with `Where`.

In your code, you should remove the `AsQueryable()` part. Without it, you should be OK:

```cs
await _context.Set<TEntity>().Where(selector).ToArrayAsync();
```

And yes, you should use an `Expresion` instead of `Func`. It's possible the `DbSet` or `DbContext` doesn't offer an overload for `Where` that accepts `Func`. That' pretty common, actually.